# Automating a python3 script for certain files across multiple directories

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

The python script needs to be ran in across multiple directories that have multiple *.pdb file. The path looks like this
/stor/project/user/user_project/folder/**.results**/*.pdb

The repository of directories are the **.results** with the desired files (*.pdb) within each directory

So far I have been running the script within each directory with input and output files being named the same as the file I want it ran on. I have little bash experience and there are too many folders to count.

The script that needs to be ran looks like this.

```
python3 /stor/project/users/scripts/script.py -p filename1.pdb >filename1.txt
```

Each .pdb file has a different name. I have tried to run other scripts but it seems the naming of .pdb file is messing it up. I need it to look for the file and output the results with the same name of the input.

The script that I have used do far is this:

```
#! /bin/bash
for d in /stor/project/cmerlos2/COLABFOLD_CAM/POSColabFold ; do
    for file in "/stor/project/cmerlos2/COLABFOLD_CAM/POSColabFold"/*.pdb
    do
        python3 /stor/project/cmerlos2/scripts/pDockQ.py -p *.pdb > *.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: Do you have code of what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

When using IO redirection (`>`) you can only specify a single target file. Furthermore, your script is looping over all files and then using a wildcard again to process all files. So you would be processing n² files. And your directory loop only loops a single directory.

What you need is [Parameter Expansion with substring processing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to construct your target file name:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "/stor/project/cmerlos2/COLABFOLD_CAM/POSColabFold"/*.pdb
do
    python3 /stor/project/cmerlos2/scripts/pDockQ.py -p "$file" > "${file%.pdb}.txt"
done
```

Other things to note:

- The hashbang must not be followed by a blank, the interpreter must come immediately after the `!` character: `#!/bin/…`
- Your script doesn't need to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) but works with [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) (`/bin/sh`) too, unless there is more codet hat you have not shown. Requiring only `/bin/sh` is more portable across different systems.
- The given script will fail for too many files in a single directory. If there are too many files, you will need to switch to `find … -exec`.